# Automatic-control-question

Tags: macros

How can I create a program that controls my computer based on commands which I have entered ahead of time.

For example:

My application should at 6pm enter facebook, enter my user credentials to log me in, and then leave a comment in the comment field which I have entered at 1PM.

Told means commend that I stored in this software.

My background is c++ and I realize programming philosophy since I program in machine language-I'm electrical engineer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is this just for your own personal usage?

If so, I would advise not actually trying to develop an application yourself for this but instead use a Macro program. About 8 years ago when I was extremeley inexperienced at programming or doing anything, I used some macro programs to create bots in games, so doing something as trivial as logging you in would be simple.

Just have it..

- Launch C:/Program Files/Mozilla/Firefox.exe (or something similar)
- Press F6
- Type: "http://www.facebook.com"
- Press `ENTER`
- Check pixel at local XXX x YYY to see if you are already logged in, in which case you don't need to enter your username and password
- If you are not logged in, move mouse to coords `XXX` and `left click`.
- Type username
- Repeat for password.
- Press `ENTER`
- Navigate to profile.
- Check the time on your system. If time is not 1PM, wait one minute and try again.
- Repeat above.
- Time is now 1PM so post your message.
- End macro.

You could make that using a program like Macro Express within about 10 minutes. It also has a Capture editor, so that you can record your own macro and then edit it as you require.

http://www.macros.com/

This answer obviously assumes it is for personal usage.

[image]